# How do I open windows that are painted closed?

Tags: windows, paint

About a month ago I painted my windows and windowsills.  The paint dried and I was able to open and close the windows at will for about a week or so after they were painted.  Then the weather got hot, we closed the windows, turned on the air conditioning for about a month.  Now the weather has cooled down and we want to open the windows again but cannot open most of them.  If it helps I painted with an exterior latex semi-gloss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go over all of the edges with a utility knife.  If that doesn't work then go in deeper with a putty knife... And if that doesn't work buy a window zipper.

Comment: I will give this a try next weekend.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup.  This worked, just using the utility knife.  I was even able to open up a window that has been painted shut since before we moved in.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your windows have a little bit of play, pull down first. You can pull down much harder than you can push up, without damaging the window. Once you hear the pop of the paint freeing, you can push up normally. I'll even put all the force on one side and then another.

You'll still want to cut away any obvious locations where the paint is sticking, but if your windows are anything like mine, this problem will be a reoccurring because the paint can get into the track itself and readhere over time. I've been dealing with windows that stick for many years now, one of the gifts of a prior home owner that wasn't careful enough. The only thing I haven't done yet is to hit the windows with some silicone lubricant to see if that would help.

Comment: Good idea.  Most of my windows do not have any give at this time so pushing them down did not seem to do much good.  I will keep that in mind for the future though, if/when this happens again.